# Getstream-io: removing activity by foreign id - not removed from any "to "feeds

Tags: getstream-io

I feel like this question was almost answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180033/how-to-remove-activity-from-multiple-feeds) but the implementation isn't working for me.

I add a comment activity to Thing A's feed and use the *to* field to notify specific users about the comment.

If I view the data explorer for Thing A I see the comment. I also see the comment in my user's notification feed.

I then delete Thing A by doing the following:

```
$feed = $client->feed("thing", "a");
$feed->removeActivity($foreignId, true);
// delete from our app DB
```

Going back to the data explorer I see that the activity is removed from Thing A's feed but still exists in my user's feed. They both share the same foreign id and from what I understand removing an activity from the *origin* feed using the foreign id will propagate that removal to all affected feeds. I've verified that the foreign id is correct.

I suppose my question is why is this not removing my activity everywhere? Is there something else I need to be doing to remove the activity from the notification feeds?

Answer (score 1):

When I run this piece of code against my personal dev app, it works. It works when `thing` is a flat feed and `user` is either a flat or a notification feed group.

```
$feed = $client->feed('thing', 1);

$feed->addActivity([
    'actor' => 'user:1',
    'verb' => 'like',
    'object' => 'post:5',
    'foreign_id' => 'like:1',
    'to' => ['user:1'],
]);

$feed->removeActivity('like:1', true);
```

If you keep having issues, please contact getstream at https://getstream.io/contact/ with more specific details (feed group names, ids, activity IDs, ...) for a closer look.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I've gotten in touch through the form.